# FileHelper read to stream and download with web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, filehelpers

I have a list of objects which I want to download as csv file via Web Api.
However when I test this with Swagger I get no csv download.
What am I doing wrong? DailyReportContent contains 2 objects.

This is my code so far:

```
public IActionResult GetDailyReport(DateTime invoiceDate)
{
    var dailyReportContent = new List<DailyReportModel>().....

    // create csv file
    var engine = new FileHelperEngine<DailyReportModel>
    {
        HeaderText = "headers.."
    };

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        engine.WriteStream(streamWriter, dailyReportContent);

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "DailyReports.csv" };

        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

And this is the response in Swagger:

```
{
  "version": {
    "major": 1,
    "minor": 1,
    "build": -1,
    "revision": -1,
    "majorRevision": -1,
    "minorRevision": -1
  },
  "content": {
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Content-Type",
        "value": [
          "text/csv"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "Content-Disposition",
        "value": [
          "attachment; filename=DailyReports.csv"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "statusCode": 200,
  "reasonPhrase": "OK",
  "headers": [],
  "requestMessage": null,
  "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

EDIT: Even if I add this:

```
 stream.Flush();
 streamWriter.Flush();

 var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
 var readResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The readResult is empty. So I guess there goes something wrong when writing the stream?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it like this:

```
var csvContent = LoadcsvContent();

var engine = new FileHelperEngine<DailyReportModel>
{
    HeaderText = "......."
};

var stream = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
engine.WriteStream(streamWriter, csvContent);

streamWriter.Flush();
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

return File(await stream, "text/csv", $"Report_{invoiceDate:yyyyMMdd}.csv");
```

Works like a charm now. Swagger output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to

```
return result;
```

Returning "Ok( < object > )" will return a response message containing the object.
You have already created your response message and specified all the content.
So I think you are returning an OK response, containing another OK response message.

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. gives me exact the same response and no download csv file. :(

Comment: What if you call the endpoint with a browser - do you get the file downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NetCore we have `return File(ret, "application/octet-stream", fileName);`

Return a file with the type we needed, in my case for an .msi package I use `"application/octet-stream"` for you you may either specify the return type as .CSV here in controller level or on the global level in `WebApiConfig` class for `Formatters`